# How to make Tree View cell inline editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, devexpress

I'm making a category tree with expand and collapse button
[image]

Now I want to make every item inline editable, can you please show me how to do that?

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-tree-ctytwm

I have tried this link but I don't see any documentation of it https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/tree-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following plugins as described at [React Grid - Editing](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/editing/):

- EditingState
- TableEditRow
- TableEditColumn

  import {
  EditingState
  } from "@devexpress/dx-react-grid";

  import {
  TableEditRow,
  TableEditColumn,
  } from "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui";

  ```
  <TreeDataState
    expandedRowIds={expandedRowIds}
    onExpandedRowIdsChange={(expandedRowIds) => {
      setExpandedRowIds(expandedRowIds);
    }}
  />
  <CustomTreeData getChildRows={getChildRows} />
  <EditingState />
  <VirtualTable />
  <TableHeaderRow />
  <TableTreeColumn for="name" />
  <TableEditRow />
  <TableEditColumn
   showAddCommand
   showEditCommand 
   showDeleteCommand 
  />
  ```

You can disable editing a particular column as described at [Disable Editing in a Column](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/editing/#disable-editing-in-a-column).

```
  const [editingStateColumnExtensions] = useState([
    { columnName: 'ebay_category', editingEnabled: false },
    { columnName: 'amazon_category', editingEnabled: false },
  ]);

      <EditingState 
        columnExtensions={editingStateColumnExtensions}
      />
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
However, I only need the Name column editable, not all row items.
https://snipboard.io/htcdTY.jpg

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This article describes how to prevent a column from being edited:https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/editing/#disable-editing-in-a-column. I've updated my answer.